# Adding [active class] - navigation element for current div with different images

Tags: jquery, html, css

my menu is like this:

```
<div id="header">
                          <div id="div-back" onClick="#">   </div>
                          <div id="div-origin" onClick="javascript:showmini('origin');">        </div>
                          <div id="div-profile" onClick="javascript:showmini('profile');">      </div>
                          <div id="div-affil" onClick="javascript:showmini('affil');">          </div>
                          <div id="div-combat" onClick="javascript:showmini('combat');">        </div>
                      </div>
```

and it's CSS:

```
#div-back {background-image:url("http://www.stipz.50webs.com/elements/mp_onhover/nm_back.png"); width:77px; height:26px; display:inline-block; float:left;}
#div-back:hover {background-image:url("http://www.stipz.50webs.com/elements/mp_onhover/on_back.png");}
#div-back:active {background-image:url("http://www.stipz.50webs.com/elements/mp_onhover/ac_back.png");}

#div-origin {background-image:url("http://www.stipz.50webs.com/elements/mp_onhover/nm_origin.png"); width:176px; height:26px; display:inline-block;float:left;}
#div-origin:hover {background-image:url("http://www.stipz.50webs.com/elements/mp_onhover/on_origin.png");}
#div-origin:active {background-image:url("http://www.stipz.50webs.com/elements/mp_onhover/ac_origin.png");}

#div-profile {background-image:url("http://www.stipz.50webs.com/elements/mp_onhover/nm_profile.png"); width:183px; height:26px; display:inline-block;float:left;}
#div-profile:hover {background-image:url("http://www.stipz.50webs.com/elements/mp_onhover/on_profile.png");}
#div-profile:active {background-image:url("http://www.stipz.50webs.com/elements/mp_onhover/ac_profile.png");}
```

*other div IDs are coded similarly, see below for a live link
because my post is getting flagged as spam.*

and it opens one div at a time

```
function showmini(holodisp) 
{
$('.holodata').each(function(index) 
{
if ($(this).attr("id") == holodisp) 
{
  $(this).fadeIn(500);
}
else 
{
$(this).fadeOut(600);
}
});
}
```

live webpage: [website portion](http://www.stipz.50webs.com/div_navigation.html)

edit: each item of the menu has 3 images for its rollover effects (normal, hover and Onclick)

The behaviour I want it to do is when a user clicks an item, 
it retains the  hover effect, adding an **active** class to change the background-image attribute seems to be the way to go but having 4 items with different background-image make it impossible for me.

Answer (score 1):

This question is really hard to understand. You add a class this way:

```
<div id="div-back" class="myclassname" onClick="#">   </div>
```

You style the class in CSS this way:

```
.myclassname { 
    background-color:#000000;
}
```

Other than that, I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: What I meant is adding class when clicking a div.
see the live webpage

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to dynamically add a class to the navigation `div` (please consider improving the markup you're using). Using jQuery, this is a starting point:

```
$('#header > div').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Have `.active` equal the `div:active` or `div:hover` styling.

When you click on another `div`, you'll want to remove previous applications of `class="active"`.

Check out my [demo code](http://codepen.io/multicelldesign/pen/YyYMyj) of accessible, bare-bones markup for what you are building.